# I have to check for browser zoom level using MSHTML library in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, selenium, mshtml

I have to check for browser zoom level using MSHTML library in vb.net. I have tried making it work in selenium by writing my desired functionality of closing the browser if it is not 100% in catch block however I can't find anything like that in mshtml.

Does anyone have any other suggestion?